# Can anyone explain why this returns between 50 to 100 of the same values? I am using this to change what a function does at a certain window width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following React code to change what a function does at a certain window width:

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState({ winWidth: 0 }); 
useEffect(() => { 
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => { 
        return setWindowWidth({ winWidth: window.innerWidth }); 
    }); 
}, [windowWidth.winWidth]);
```

The console just shows `1000` over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the resize event triggers repeatedly while a resize is happening. You probably want to add some sort of [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) to your resize process.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setWindowWidth` that changes `windowWidth.winWidth` which is in your useEffect's dependency array. Adding multiple event listeners to `resize`.

You should pass an empty dependecy array.

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState({ winWidth: 0 }); 
useEffect(() => { 
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => { 
        return setWindowWidth({ winWidth: window.innerWidth }); 
    }); 
}, []); // empty dependency array
```